Is $b\in im(f)$ whenever $k.b\in im(f)$ for a group homomorphism $f$
Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of abelian groups, and let $b$ be an element of $B$. Suppose that $k \cdot b \in \operatorname{im}(f)$ for some positive integer $k$, where $\operatorname{im}(f)$ denotes the image of $f$.
Question: Is $b \in \operatorname{im}(f)$ ? （If we replace $\operatorname{im}(f)$ with $\operatorname{ker}(f)$, what can we conclude?）

Hint:
Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_3\to \mathbb{Z}_2$ be the trivial homomorphism ($f(x)=1$), where $\mathbb{Z}_3=\langle x\rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2=\langle y\rangle$. Then $y^2=1 \in \mathrm{im}f$, but $y\not\in\mathrm{im}f$.
